# Marshmallow Heads-up Notifications Gone?

Tags: notifications

My Galaxy S6 edge recently updated to Android 6.0.1.

Before, when I would get a message from Whatsapp, it would show the message at the top of my screen (Lollipop called it Heads-up notification). Now, only the icon shows up at the top of the screen and I have to pull down the screen in order to see who its from.

It's really irritating! Please help me get that feature back or advise me how to return to Lollipop. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The update never removed Heads Up notifications. You just have to select which apps have the permission to display them.

Go into `Settings -> Sound & notification -> App notifications` to pull up a list of apps.

Once you select `Whatsapp` in your case, there will be an `"Allow Peeking"` checkbox, as so:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [staticworld.net](http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2015/10/screenshot_20151008-114904-100620875-medium.png))</sub>

Just tick that back on, and you'll get those notifications.

---

If WhatsApp doesn't respect those settings, there is an alternative:

- You can download a [Fully Customizable Heads-up for WhatsApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.floatify) from Play Store, which works with the latest WhatsApp update.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI, i have done that but still only the icon comes up at the top and doesnt display the name ect with it!

Comment: @Suzie added an alternative! Hope it works!

Comment: I can't find this for the messages app on my GS6.